# using a $variable as a html value in php

Tags: php

Here I use a sql to find 2 fields from my database. Now i want to use the 'PubID' as a 'value' for the option to use in another query and 'PubName' to show as the result to the user.

It displays correctly with the 'PubName', but I don't believe the option holds the value of 'PubID' as my seperate query doesn't work.

Is what I'm trying to code possible in php? if so could anyone help? thanks

```
while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
    echo "<tr> <th> Publisher</th> </tr>";
    echo "<td class='select'>" . "<select class='text-black input-button-rounded' name='Publisher'>";
    echo "<option disabled selected value=" . $row3['PubID'] . ">" . $row3['PubName'] . "</option>"; 
    echo "<option class='text-black' value='1'>Frostwhite</option> ";
    echo "<option class='text-black' value='2'>Naughty Cat</option>";
    echo "<option class='text-black' value='3'>ET</option>";
    echo "<option class='text-black' value='4'>Pillows</option>";
    echo "<option class='text-black' value='5'>Treetime</option>";
    echo "<option class='text-black' value='6'>TableTop</option>";
    echo "</select></td><br>";
}
```

Comment: You need to escape the `$` using `\$`. Sorry the question is not clear...

Comment: Quote the attribute value. If `$row3['PubID']` contains a space that will be read as a separate attribute currently. You also don't need all the `echo`s. e.g. `value='" . $row3['PubID'] . "'>" .`

Comment: Replace `"<option disabled selected value=" . $row3['PubID'] . ">" . $row3['PubName'] . "</option>";` with `"<option disabled selected value=\"" . $row3['PubID'] . "\">" . $row3['PubName'] . "</option>";`

Answer (score 0):

As @chris85 and @Kraang Prime mentioned you have to replace this:

```
echo "<option disabled selected value=" . $row3['PubID'] . ">" . $row3['PubName'] . "</option>";
```

to that:

```
echo "<option disabled selected value='{$row3['PubID']}'> {$row3['PubName']} </option>";
```

So answer for your question - yes it is possible).

And you mentioned that:

> don't believe the option holds the value of 'PubID'

you can verify this value for example in browser by hitting "Inspect" in context menu for your select html element.